# Converting from DOM property to enum in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, enums, typescript

I've got a enum like this:

```
enum Steps {
    Step1,
    Step2,
    ...
}
```

I've tried to use it in a few different ways:

```
var cur_step : Steps = Steps[$(this).prop('data-step').toString()]; // compiler error
var str : string = $(this).prop('data-step').toString(); // no error
var cur_step : Steps = Steps[$(this).attr('data-step')];
var cur_step : Steps = Steps[String($(this).prop('data-step'))];
var cur_step : Steps = Steps[<string>$(this).prop('data-step')];
```

The first conversion from property to enum gives me a compiler error:

> Cannot convert 'string' to '{ Step1: Steps; Step2: Steps; [x: number]: string; }': Type 'String' is missing property 'Step1' from type '{ Step1: Steps; Step2: Steps; [x: number]: string; }'.

Why doesn't the first method work? `toString()` returns a base type of string for all instances of the method in `lib.d.ts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**: Calling `toString()` on a variable of type `any` doesn't return a string. You can cast instead using `<string>`. Full details below.

Conversion from string to enum is as you describe - here is an example that definitely works...

```
enum Steps {
    Step1,
    Step2,
    Step3
}

var propValue = 'Step3';

var currentStep: Steps = Steps[propValue];
```

[See this running](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=enum%20Steps%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Step1,%0A%20%20%20%20Step2,%0A%09Step3%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20propValue%20=%20%27Step3%27;%0A%0Avar%20currentStep%3a%20Steps%20=%20Steps%5BpropValue%5D;%0A%0Aalert%28currentStep.toString%28%29%29;)

The compiler allows any property or function to be called on an `any` type (prop returns `any` in your case) and it doesn't infer the outcome. So `toString()` in this instance is not assumed to be the real version that returns a string. Here is an example using your code:

```
var x = $(this).prop('data-step').toString(); // x is any
```

And a short version of the example to prove the point:

```
var d: any;
d = 'test';
var e = d.toString(); // e is any
```

So to get around this with your example in a single line, you can use:

```
var currentStep: Steps = Steps[<string>$(this).prop('data-step')];
```

Comment: You've confirmed my usage but I'm not convinced you've answered my question. What I don't get is when I look through all the declarations of toString() in all the interfaces of lib.d.ts, it's `toString(): string;` (even the globally declared function toString outside of all interfaces) so how come calling toString() on a `Any` type returns a `Any`, is this defined or stated somewhere?

Comment: When you call any method on a variable of type `any` it will return `any`. That includes `toString`, `madeUpThing` or `anythingYouLike`. This is from section 3.1 of the specification: `supports the same operations as a value in JavaScript and minimal static type checking is performed for operations`

Comment: If the prop call in jQuery returns a string, the jquery.d.ts could be amended - I'd have to check the jQuery docs first.

Comment: prop in jquery.d.ts correctly returns `Any` because a property could hold number, bool, json so there's no confusion there. I had a look at the spec, it's not as specific or definitive as I'd like. It's implying that since there isn't much type checking, that it will always default to `Any` but doesn't actually state it. Accepted for clearing it up for me though, thanks!